# How get fist set of thousand records and next set of thousand records using for loop in Netsuite 'N/search Module'

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, netsuite, suitescript

I want to  process first set of thousand records and then next set of thousand records from the search results obtained from the Search Results .

**i'm getting the first set of thousand records using the method available in suitescript 2.0 version'N/search' module's  Method (getRange(0,1000)).**

**CODE:**

```
var mySearch = search.load({
id: 'customsearch_employee'
});
var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange(0, 100);
for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
var entity = searchResult[i].getValue({
name: 'entity'
});
});
```

I want know how to process next set of thousand records using the for loops.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SuiteScript 2.0 provides a paging API for you. I'll explain a bit first, and then show an example.

After you create your search object `mySearch`, instead of calling `run()`, you call `runPaged()` to run a paged search, which has an optional `pageSize` parameter that allows you to specify how many results per page. Default value is `50`.

`runPaged` returns a `PagedData` object that contains the list of pages of results in its `pageRanges` property. You actually retrieve the results on each page by calling `fetch` on the page.

This example is taken straight from the Help page for `N/search`, but I've added some explanatory comments.

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['N/search'], function(search) {
    function loadAndRunSearch() {
        // Load your search into memory
        var mySearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_my_so_search'
        });

        // Run paged version of search with 1000 results per page
        var myPagedData = mySearch.runPaged({
            "pageSize": 1000
        });

        // Iterate over each page
        myPagedData.pageRanges.forEach(function(pageRange){

            // Fetch the results on the current page
            var myPage = myPagedData.fetch({index: pageRange.index});

            // Iterate over the list of results on the current page
            myPage.data.forEach(function(result){

                // Process the individual result
                var entity = result.getValue({
                    name: 'entity'
                });
                var subsidiary = result.getValue({
                    name: 'subsidiary'
                });
            });
        });
    }
    loadAndRunSearch();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the next range using :

```
var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange(1000, 2000);
```

In a loop you can check the length and get all the results:

```
var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange(0, 1000) || []; 
var i = 1000;
while(searchResult.length >= 1000){
i+= 1000;
searchResult = searchResult.concat((mySearch.run().getRange(i, i+1000) || []));
}
```